# To prove that a sum of powers is composite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove that $5^{20} + 2^{14}$ is a composite number?

Comment: Have you already tried checking for small-prime divisors (by computing each term modulo $p$)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm As user236182's solution shows, that would not have helped ...

Comment: Have more faith in the computers of today…(although, as mentioned in a comment below the solution, this is a very lucky case...)

Comment: @Hagen: I see, but that doesn't invalidate the fact that askers should still disclose the simple things they've tried that _don't_ work.

Comment: Small comment: $5^{20}+2^{14}=95367431657009$. You only need to check all integers less than (or equal to) the square root of that, i.e. $9765625.00083886$. That's about 10 million trial divisions, i.e. nothing that a modern computer (in my case a five-year old macbook) cannot do in a few seconds.

Answer (score 7):

$$5^{20}+2^{14}=\left(5^{10}+2^{7}\right)^2-\left(5^{5}2^{4}\right)^2$$

$$=\left(5^{10}+2^7+5^5 2^4\right)\left(5^{10}+2^7-5^5 2^4\right)$$

The key here is [Sophie Germain identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity). Note that the prime factorization is $5^{20}+2^{14} = 937\cdot 10369\cdot 9815753$, so the prime factors are quite large.

Comment: Brute-force trial division in a language supporting big integers (Java, Python, etc.) immediately finds the factors 937 and 10369. Finding even the lesser one of them is enough to prove compositeness. Hence this is quite a lucky case…but suffice it to say, your solution is much nicer.